# Huggingface TFBertForSequenceClassification always predicts the same label

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

TL;DR:
My model always predicts the same labels and I don't know why. Below is my entire code for fine-tuning in the hopes that someone can point out to me where I am going wrong.

I am using Huggingface's TFBertForSequenceClassification for sequence classification task to predict 4 labels of sentences in German text.

I use the bert-base-german-cased model since I don't use only lower case text (since German is more case sensitive than English).

I get my input from a csv file that I construct from an annotated corpus I received. Here's a sample of that:

```
0       Hier kommen wir ins Spiel Die App Cognitive At...
1       Doch wenn Athlet Lebron James jede einzelne Mu...
2       Wie kann ein Gehirn auf Hochleistung getrimmt ...
3       Wie schafft es Warren Buffett knapp 1000 Wörte...
4       Entfalte dein mentales Potenzial und werde ein...
Name: sentence_clean, Length: 3094, dtype: object
```

And those are my labels, from the same csv file:

```
0       e_1
1       e_4
2       e_4
3       e_4
4       e_4
```

The distinct labels are: e_1, e_2, e_3, and e_4

This is the code I am using to fine tune my model:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
    
# read in data
# sentences_df = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv')


X = sentences_df.sentence_clean
Y = sentences_df.classId

# =============================================================================
# One hot encode labels
# =============================================================================

# integer encode labels
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y_integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(list(Y))


# one hot encode labels
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
Y_integer_encoded_reshaped = Y_integer_encoded.reshape(len(Y_integer_encoded), 1)
Y_one_hot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(Y_integer_encoded_reshaped)

# train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_one_hot_encoded, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)


# =============================================================================
# Perpare datasets for finetuning
# =============================================================================
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertForSequenceClassification


tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-german-cased') # initialize tokenizer


# tokenize trai and test sets
max_seq_length = 128

X_train_tokens = tokenizer(list(X_train_raw),
                            truncation=True,
                            padding=True)

X_test_tokens = tokenizer(list(X_test_raw),
                            truncation=True,
                            padding=True)


# create TF datasets as input for BERT model
bert_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(X_train_tokens),
    y_train
))

bert_test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(X_test_tokens),
    y_test
))

# =============================================================================
# setup model and finetune
# =============================================================================

# define hyperparams
num_labels = 4
learninge_rate = 2e-5
epochs = 3
batch_size = 16

# create BERT model
bert_categorical_partial = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-german-cased', num_labels=num_labels)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learninge_rate)
bert_categorical_partial.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = bert_categorical_partial.fit(bert_train_ds.shuffle(100).batch(batch_size),
          epochs=epochs,
          # batch_size=batch_size,
          validation_data=bert_test_ds.shuffle(100).batch(batch_size))
```

And here is the output from fine-tuning:

```
Epoch 1/3
155/155 [==============================] - 31s 198ms/step - loss: 8.3038 - accuracy: 0.2990 - val_loss: 8.7751 - val_accuracy: 0.2811
Epoch 2/3
155/155 [==============================] - 30s 196ms/step - loss: 8.2451 - accuracy: 0.2913 - val_loss: 8.9314 - val_accuracy: 0.2779
Epoch 3/3
155/155 [==============================] - 30s 196ms/step - loss: 8.3101 - accuracy: 0.2913 - val_loss: 9.0355 - val_accuracy: 0.2746
```

Lastly, I try to predict the labels of the test set and validate the results with a confusion matrix:

```
X_test_tokens_new = {'input_ids': np.asarray(X_test_tokens['input_ids']),
                     'token_type_ids': np.asarray(X_test_tokens['token_type_ids']),
                     'attention_mask': np.asarray(X_test_tokens['attention_mask']),
                     }

pred_raw = bert_categorical_partial.predict(X_test_tokens_new)
pred_proba = tf.nn.softmax(pred_raw).numpy()
pred = pred_proba[0].argmax(axis = 1)
y_true = y_test.argmax(axis = 1)

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, pred)
```

Output of print(cm):

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,  41],
       [  2,   0,   0, 253],
       [  2,   0,   0, 219],
       [  6,   0,   0,  96]], dtype=int64)
```

As you can see, my accuracy is really bad, and when I look at the cm, I can see that my model pretty much just predicts one single label.
I've tried everything and ran the model multiple times, but I always get the same results.
I do know that the data I am working with isn't great and I am only training on abour 2k sentences with labels. But I have a feeling the accuracy should still be higher and, more importantly, the model shouldn't just predict one single label 98% of the time, right?

I posted everything I am using to run the model in the hopes someone can point me to where I am going wrong.
Thank very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you perform `LabelEncoding` and then `OneHotEncoding`on the `Y` data?

Comment: how your labels distributed (how much of e1, e2, e3, e4 in your data) ? You trained just for 465 steps of 2000 sentences. I think that the number of e4 is 30%, so it is easier for the model to predict only this labels. Try to train for 50 epochs.

Comment: @yudhiesh I needed to get the labels into a numeric format in order for OneHotEncoder to work in this case, hence why I did the interim step. The one hot vectors should be correct though, I double checked the outputs and they align with the labels (so e_1 being at position 0, e_2 at 1, etc)

Comment: @Andrey, the entire dataset contains about 6.3% e_1, 38.8% e_2, 37.6% e_3 and 17.4% e_4 labels, so you guess was close. To be honest, I don't completely understand the steps. When I train for 150 steps each epoch, does this mean I only train on 450 observations in total? How can I adjust this?

I've tried training up to 10 epochs, but the accuracy just got stuck after the third epoch. I will try running for 50 and see what happens. However, I thought BERT is so powerful because it doesn't need that many epochs to achieve good results, no? Isn't that part of the purpose of Transfer Learning ?

Comment: @alxgal you train of all data every epochs. But you do it by steps, and you train one batch every step. Number of epochs depends on a number of trainable variables and on a volume of training data. If your data is small - you need to train more epochs. How many trainable variables in your model ? You are right about the purpose of Transfer learning. If you trained you rmodel from the very start - it would take months. Using transfer learning it could take hours. But definitely not in a couple of minutes even of TPU even on a 1 mln samples.

Comment: @alxgal I would advice to decrease learning rate to get your accuracy encreasing after every epoch (for the first 10 epochs)

Comment: I decrease the learning rate to 1e-6 and trained over 10 epochs: results are much better actually and the model predicts different labels. I'm now training for 50 epochs as you originally suggested and will keep you in the loop!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227221/discussion-between-alxgal-and-andrey).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You trained for a couple of minutes. It is not enough even for pretrained BERT.

Try to decrease learning rate to get your accuracy increasing after every epoch (for the first 10 epochs). And train for more epochs (until you see the validation accuracy decreasing for 10 epochs).

Comment: So I did exactly that per your comment. I trained for 50 epochs with a learning rate of 1e-6.
I got 41.2% val accuracy during epoch 25, and then it started decreasing down to 5.01% in epoch 50. Does that mean that I should just use 25 epochs to train the model then?

Comment: @alxgal yes, you data is too small and the model is overfitting after 25 epochs. But you can play with learning rate further.

Comment: That makes sense, however I do have one more question for you: when you say my model overfits the data, wouldn't that mean that my train accuracy would be very high (like 99%)? It's decreases down to around 5% as well, so train and val accuracy are always around 2% of each other.

Comment: @yes, normally your training accuracy should increase. Not to 99%, but it should not decrease (should stay stable after some number of epochs). But NN optimizes training loss not accuracy. In theory it could decrease, but training loss should not decrease definitely. How does training loss behave ?

Comment: The loss is generally rather high, which I believe makes sense given the small amount of data in the dataset and the poor performance. The loss starts at ~5, then hovers between 6 and 7.5 until it arrives at 7.34 during the last epoch. Yes, that is 7.34 and not 0.734.

Comment: @alxgal Loss value doen't matter (it is not probability). But it should decrease. Try to decrease learning rate further